# Clases get y set en poo de javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
let prop = document.getElementById('propietario').nodeValue;
let nombreMascota = document.getElementById('nombreMascota').nodeValue;
let direccion = getElementById('direccion').value;
let telefono = document.getElementById('telefono').value;
let enfermedad = document.getElementById('enfermedad').value;
let tipo = document.getElementById('tipo').value;

if(tipo=="perro") {
let perro = new nombreMascota(propo,direccion,telefono,tipo,nombreMascota,enfermedad);
    mostrarResult(perro);
}
else if(tipo=="gato"){
    let gato = new nombreMascota(propo,direccion,telefono,tipo,nombreMascota,enfermedad);
    mostrarResult(gato);
}
else if(tipo=="conejo") {
    let conejo = new nombreMascota(propo,direccion,telefono,tipo,nombreMascota,enfermedad);
    mostrarResult(conejo); 
}

let mostrarResult = (valor)=> {
    let resultado = document.querySelector('#resultado ul')
    resultado.innerHTML=" ";
    
    let li1 = document.createElement('li');
    li1.innerHTML=`${valor.datosPropietario()}`;
    let li2 = document.createElement('li');
    li2.innerHTML = `${valor.tipo()}, mientras que el nombre de la mascota es : ${valor.nombreM()} y la enfermedad es :${valor.enfermedad()}`;
    resultado.appendChild(li1);
    resultado.appendChild(li2);
}

formulario.addEventListener('submit',observarForm);
class Propietario {
    constructor(nombreP,direccion,telefono){
        this.nombreP=nombreP;
        this.direccion=direccion;
        this.telefono=telefono;
    }
    datosPropietario(){
        return `El nombre del dueño es : ${this.nombreP} El domicilio es : ${this.direccion}, y el telefono de contacto : ${this.telefono}`;

    }
};

class Animal extends Propietario {
    constructor(nombreP,direccion,telefono,tipo){
        super(nombreP,direccion,telefono)
        this.tipo=tipo;
    }
    get tipo(){
        return `El tipo de animal es un : ${this._tipo}`;
    }
    };

class Mascota extends Animal {
    constructor(nombreP,direccion,telefono,tipo,nombreM,enfermedad){
        super(nombreP,direccion,telefono,tipo);
        this._nombreM=nombreM;
        this._enfermedad=enfermedad;
    }
    get nombreM(){
        return this._nombreM    }
    get enfermedad() {
        return this._enfermedad    }

    set nombreM(nombreM_nuevo){
        this.nombreM=nombreM_nuevo;    }

    set enfermedad(enfermedad_nuevo){
        this._enfermedad=enfermedad_nuevo;    }
        
}
```

```css
form {
    font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Tajawal:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">
    <title>Desafio</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="mx-auto text-center">
            <img src="./assets/img/conejo-perro-gato.jpg" alt="animales" class="img-fluid">
            <h2 class="my-3">Consulta Veterinaria</h2>
        </div>
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="propietario">Dueño: </label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="propietario" aria-describedby="textoAyuda">
              <small id="textoAyuda" class="form-text text-muted">Nunca compartiremos tus datos.</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="telefono">Numero Telefonico: </label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefono">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="direccion">Lugar de Residencia: </label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="direccion">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="nombreMascota">Nombre de la Mascota: </label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombreMascota">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="tipo">Tipo</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="tipo">
                  <option value="perro">Perro</option>
                  <option value="gato">Gato</option>
                  <option value="conejo">Conejo</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="enfermedad">Motivo de la consulta: </label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="enfermedad">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
          </form>
          <div class="text-center mt-5">
              <p>Datos Agregados</p>
              <div id="resultado">
                  <ul></ul>
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    <script src="./assets/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

El codigo anterior está diseñado para ingresar información a un formulario , si bien no está conectado con una base de datos , al menos debiera mostrar que recibió los datos ingresados . El documento html no reacciona al ingresar la información solicitada. Es decir su comportamiento es independiente a que esté conectado con el archivo javascript. No sé claramente qué es lo que falta para que quede un archivo plenamente funcional, porque errores no entrega . Por esa razón lo público , para ver si hay alguien que pueda estudiar el codigo e indicarme qué se debe agregar al javascript para que quede plenamente funcional.

Answer (score 2):

Voy a tratar de responder claro, pero tampoco es para resolverlo y entregártelo ya hecho, no es esa la función de esta comunidad. Es cuestionable que no te hayas dado cuenta de este tipo de errores y omisiones que tuviste Si eres nuevo en el mundo de la programación te sugiero que seas mas minucioso. Te ayudará muchísimo en el futuro:

1.- Tu primera propiedad se llama `prop` y cuando instancias tus objetos *perro, gato y conejo* usas `propo`

2.- Escuchas un evento de la variable `formulario` que debería ser un elemento del DOM, pero nunca asignaste ningun elemento a esa variable (*asumo que querías escuchar el evento submit del único formulario que tienes*)

3.- Dentro de `formulario.addEventListener()` haces referencia a una función `observarForm`, pero no encuentro esa función en ninguna parte del código que proporcionaste.

4.- Dentro de esta función a la que hace referencia `observarForm` es donde deberías hacer la declaración y asignación de tus variables `prop`, `nombreMascota`, `direccion`, `telefono`, `enfermedad` y `tipo`, ya que tal como está cuando ingresas los datos en tu formulario no vas a notar ningun cambio en sus valores vacíos.

Comment: Gracias por responder . Hice algunos arreglos , como agregar en la linea tres del js , el término document , cambié la función en el addEventListener a mostrarResult , la que sí esta definida , y cambié la propiedad a prop . Pero ahora sale el arror  new nombreMascota(prop,direccion,telefono,tipo,nombreMascota,enfermedad); , señalando que nombreMascota no es un constructor. te dejo la inquietud. Pero también subiré una nueva pregunta con este tema

Comment: @Pedro, pero si no editas la pregunta con estos cambios no podremos ver los errores restantes. No veo ninguna clase que se llame *nombreMascota*